# get Wifi SSID with QT 6.5

Tags: qt, wifi, qtnetwork

With the removal of QNetworkConfigurationManager, how can we found the SSID from QT when we are connected by Wifi ? II try to use QNetworkInterface, but I cannot found the SSID and QNetworkSettingsManager is not working in windows or linux. Any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Laurent